# How to Display Data from a Source to a Page with Ajax.?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a GameServer which is posting few data in POST format
to my WebServer(Apache) every 5 secs.

I want that data to be displayed in some page and update it live as Gameserver resend data every 5 secs.

I mean Ajax live View.

Any Answer? Plz :)

Comment: If the webserver puts the data in a database, write another page that sends an AJAX request to retrieve the data and display it. It can use `setInterval()` to repeat this every few seconds to get the lastest data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i see:

1. GameServer POST data to server, every 5 sec and store it somewhere.
2. Ajax asking server every 5 sec about the data and display it on the screen.

html

```
<div id="divContainer"></div>
```

jquery

```
setInterval(function() {
    var handler = 'getdata';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'parser.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            handler:handler
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#divContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

parser.php

```
$handler = $_POST[handler];

if($handler == 'getdata'){
// your code to retrieve game data ( from db, session etc, depend on the game logic)
    echo $gamedata;
}
```